# Using JwtStrategy in Nestjs when secretOrKey is not available

Tags: jwt, passport.js, amazon-cognito, nestjs, passport-jwt

I am trying to integrate AWS Cognito into my Nestjs application, because Nodejs applications do not support using secretOrKey with AWS Cognito, I am looking for a way to implement this using `secretOrKeyProvider`, but I need help understand whether and if yes, then how I can do it.

This is my current implementation of the JwtStrategy:

```js
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClaimVerifyResult, handler } from './jwt.verify';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: true,
      secretOrKeyProvider: (_, token, done) => {
        //token here is valid
        //token has not expired
        //calling {handler} function here will return a valid user entity
        //calling done here with the valid user will still result in unauthorized
        return token;
      },
    });
  }

  public async validate(
    payload: any,
    done: (err: Error | null, result: ClaimVerifyResult) => void,
  ) {
    console.log('validating');
    const userInfo = await handler(payload);
    if (!userInfo) {
      return done(new UnauthorizedException(), null);
    }
    done(null, userInfo);
  }
}
```

I can get inside the `secretOrKeyProvider` feedback, but I cannot seem to get the `validate` function to be invoked.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I have the same problem

Comment: Hi Adam, yes, I've done an article on it on medium:  https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/authentication-with-aws-cognito-and-nestjs-9f04c766f3fd